# How to weight records in sklearn RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, resampling

Suppose I have 10,000 records with low error in measurements, and 10,000 records with high error, where the high error records have 2X the error in target value measurement. I want to give a higher weight to low-error measurements, and realize I could resample the data, but that has the disadvantage of increasing time and space.

Let's consider this problem for `RandomForestRegressor` or `GradientBoostingRegressor` in sklearn. Each has `sample_weight` available to the `fit` and `score` methods. Can `sample_weight` be used to account for varying degrees of confidence in the records? Or, are there better approaches than resampling to expressing relative degrees of confidence in each record of the training data? How should sample_weight respond to the proportion of expected error in the two sets of records I have?